# Will the new PayPal checkout page be made available for "PayPal Payments Standard" as well?

Tags: paypal

I use "PayPal Payments Standard" currently and the checkout page looks like this:

[image]

Some websites I noticed that are using "PayPal Express Checkout" have the new checkout page like this:

[image: new]

Does anybody know if the new page will be made available for Payments Standard as well?